# How to calculate a list without loop?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, vector, infinite-loop

I have pairs of numbers `{a1, b1}`, `{a2, b2}`, `{a3, b3}`, ..., `{aN, bN}`

What is the shortest way to compute and plot `{a1, b1}`, `{a2, b1+b2}`, `{a3, b1+b2+b3}`,....?

Comment: `{as, bs} = Transpose[pairs]; result = Transpose[{as, Accumulate[bs]}]`

Comment: Or, `Transpose[MapAt[Accumulate, Transpose[pairs], 2]]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Accumulate@Array[b, {3}]
(* {b[1], b[1] + b[2], b[1] + b[2] + b[3]} *)
```

therefore:

```
{a, b} = Transpose[list];
Transpose[{a, Accumulate[b]}]
```

Also this will do the job:

```
Rest@FoldList[{#2[[1]], #1[[2]] + #2[[2]]} &, {0, 0}, list]
```

or even easier

```
list[[All,2]]=Accumulate@list[[All,2]]; list
```

Answer (score 11):

```
FoldList[{0, 1} # + #2 &, list]
```

Answer (score 6):

thanks to Mike Honeychurch, without pure function:

```
list = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};
Thread[{Thread[list][[1]], Rest@FoldList[Plus, 0, Thread[list][[2]]]}]
(* {{a1, b1}, {a2, b1 + b2}, {a3, b1 + b2 + b3}} *)
```

and shorter (one expression):

```
Thread[{list[[All, 1]], Accumulate[list][[All, 2]]}]
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more how `Rest@FoldList` structure works?

Comment: @Maria. `Rest` just removes first element in the list, i.e. `Rest[{1, 2, 3}]` gives {2, 3}. `@` is a shorthand for head application. So `Rest@FoldList[...]` is the same as `Rest[FoldList[...]]`. Finally, `FoldList[Plus, 0, {a, b, c}]` gives `{0, a, a + b, a + b + c}.` Now you may see why we need `Rest` - just to get rid of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way and an active effort to advertise the [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that was developed by @Sjoerd Smit.

To the extend of my knowledge it was first suggested in [**`this answer`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157305/function-addition-declaring-function-as-the-total-of-a-list-of-functions/277661#277661).

```
list = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};
list[[All, 1]]
ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{Accumulate}][
  list[[All, 2]]] // Flatten
Thread[{%%, %}]
```

> `{{a1, b1}, {a2, b1 + b2}, {a3, b1 + b2 + b3}}`

Comment: (+1) `ThroughOperator` is very flexible, so I hope they consider it as an option in a future version. Nicely done, mate! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks a lot! Indeed it is very flexible and bypasses some issues that non-resource functions have. Hopefully, they will consider, but who knows?

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation using `FoldList` and `MapAt`:

```
pairs = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};

f = FoldList[Apply[Plus]@*Flatten@*List, Nothing, #] &;
```

By entering `Nothing` instead of zero as the initial element in `FoldList`, we avoid the need to use `Rest` to remove the first element of the cumulative list. This choice makes the code cleaner and avoids the need to handle special cases.

```
Transpose@MapAt[f, Transpose@pairs, 2]

(*{{a1, b1}, {a2, b1 + b2}, {a3, b1 + b2 + b3}}*)
```

As the version proposed by @J. M.'s eventual burnout in a comment, but without using `Accumulate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[Accumulate, list, {All, 2}]
```

{{a1, b1}, {a2, b1 + b2}, {a3, b1 + b2 + b3}}