# Function addition - Declaring function as the Total of a list of functions

Tags: function-construction

I'm having a problem concerning function addition. The following code shows an example that illustrates my problem. I had this list of functions that have the same variable. I had them by using the Total function and declared a function of that variable equal to the Total[list], like in this example:

```
f1[x_] := 2 x + 1;
f2[x_] := x;
f3[x_] = 4 x;
l1 = List[f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]];
o[x_] := Total[l1];
o[1]
```

The output of `o[1]` was `1+7x`, instead of `8`, which is what I want. Any suggestion on how to approach this problem? 
Thank you

Comment: If you do this, you'll get  8 `f1[x_] := 2 x + 1;
f2[x_] := x;
f3[x_] = 4 x;
l1[x_] := List[f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]];
o[x_] := Total[l1[x]];
o[1]`

Comment: On top of what @Nasser gave you, the issue with your code has to do with how variables are scoped. The `x_` parameter is scoped differently from the `x` symbol you provide in `l1`. So you could also mostly keep your code but replace `o` with this: ``o[v_] := Total[l1] /. x -> v``

Comment: Or include `Evaluate` in definition of `o[x_]`, i.e., `o[x_] := Evaluate@Total[l1];`

Comment: @BobHanlon [There is a shortcut for the combination of `SetDelayed` and `Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (as a side note, when defining functions using `SetDelayed` one doesn't have to include the semi-colon at the end of the line).

```
f1[x_] := 2 x + 1
f2[x_] := x
f3[x_] := 4 x
```

Use `SetDelayed` (i.e., `:=`) again to defrine `l1`

```
l1[x_] := List[f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]]
```

Inside the defintion for `o` use `l1` with an argument

```
o[x_] := Total[l1[x]]
```

Then test

```
o[1]
(* 8 *)

o[2]
(* 15 *)
```

This is similar but not quite identical to what **Nasser** wrote in his comment.

Comment: Is it possible to get a specific element of the l1 list, now that it is a list of functions?

Comment: `l1[x][[2]]` would, for example, get element 2

Answer (score 4):

My  new resource function [ThroughOperator](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) can do this:

```
f1[x_] := 2 x + 1;
f2[x_] := x;
f3[x_] := 4 x;
o = ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][f1 + f2 + f3];
o /@ Range[5]
```

> {8, 15, 22, 29, 36}

If you have a list of functions or if somehow the expression `f1 + f2 + f3` evaluates to something else inside of `ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"]`, you can also use:

```
list = {f1, f2, f3};
o = ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][list, Plus];
o /@ Range[5]
```

Comment: Nice answer! What 's the advantage of this ResourceFunction compared to a list of pure functions `{f1,f2,f3}` and  `Total@Through[{f1, f2, f3}[5]]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `Through[{f1, f2, f3}[5]]` is annoying to map over lists, which is one of the main motivations I made `ThroughOperator`. Another reason is that `Through[h[f1, f2][x]]` sometimes suffers from order-of-evaluation issues that are difficult to circumvent.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!