# Perform Apply[] to a sum of objects

Tags: functions

is there any way to use the `Apply[]` function to a sum of objects? By this I mean the following. We know that using `Apply[]` (`@@`) to an objects gives:

```
f@@{a}
f[a]
```

I'm wondering if there's a way of doing something like

```
(f+g)@@{a}
f[a]+g[a]
```

Does anyone knows anything about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you require `Through[Sequence@@@(f + g)@{a}]` or  `Through[(f + g)[a]]`? (or `Sequence@@@(f + g)@{a}//Through`)

Comment: `#@a & /@ (f + g)`

Comment: Also `Through[(f + g)[a]]` or `Through[(f + g) @@ {a}]`

Comment: Thanks! All these work!

Answer (score 5):

As of version 14.0, `ComapApply` is introduced:

```
ComapApply[f + g, {a}]
(* f[a] + g[a] *)

ComapApply[f + g]@{a}
(* f[a] + g[a] *)
```

[image]

BTW, if the *object* isn't a `List` `{}`, you can directly use `Comap` (also new in *v14*):

```
Comap[f + g, a]
(* f[a] + g[a] *)

Comap[f + g]@a
(* f[a] + g[a] *)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is another way and an active effort to advertise the [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that was developed by @Sjoerd Smit. This is rather new and I find it convenient.

To the extend of my knowledge it was first suggested in [**`this answer`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157305/function-addition-declaring-function-as-the-total-of-a-list-of-functions/277661#277661).

```
fnctns = {f, g};
oprtr = ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][fnctns, Plus];
```

and then

```
oprtr /@ {a} /. List -> (# &)
```

> [image: res]

Comment: Does this accomplish anything that `Though[(f+g)[a]]` doesn't? Why should we rely on an external solution when an internal one exists?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi did you visit any of the links I provided? I am asking out of curiosity

Comment: Yes, I visited the links.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi in the second link there's this explanation in a comment `Through[{f1, f2, f3}[5]] is annoying to map over lists, which is one of the main motivations I made ThroughOperator. Another reason is that Through[h[f1, f2][x]] sometimes suffers from order-of-evaluation issues that are difficult to circumvent` which for me at least was enough to give it a go. Also, I just suggested this an alternative. I realize what the easiest way is.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Finally, there's a wealth of very helpful undocumented commands in Mathematica. And finally, I believe that just because there's a simple way of doing things does not mean we should disregard other options. I find it pedagogical.

Comment: Glad to see my function is being used :)

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I am still in the process of learning how to use it properly, so the above answer was a good small exercise. Congrats. It's very nice!