# Distribute arguments over a function in all ordered combinations

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, combinatorics

I'm looking for a function that can do this

```
applyDistributed[F, Dot[a, b, c]]
= {Dot[F[a, b, c]],
  Dot[F[a, b], F[c]],
  Dot[F[a], F[b, c]],
  Dot[F[a], F[b], F[c]]}
```

Honestly I don't even know where to start. I can't imagine how to program in the number of arguments that F should take

Comment: Do you mean this? applyDistributed[F_, a_, b_, c_] := {Dot[F[a, b, c]], 
  Dot[F[a, b], F[c]], Dot[F[a], F[b, c]], Dot[F[a], F[b], F[c]]}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

Using @bmf' s definition for the partitioning

```
applyDistributed[func_, x_] :=
 Module[{list = List @@ x, func2 = Head@x},
  func2 @@@ Apply[func, Internal`PartitionRagged[list, #] & /@
     Apply[Join, Permutations /@
       IntegerPartitions[Length[list]]], {2}]]

applyDistributed[F, a . b . c]

(* {F[a, b, c], F[a, b] . F[c], F[a] . F[b, c], F[a] . F[b] . F[c]} *)

applyDistributed[F, a*b*c]

(* {F[a, b, c], F[c] F[a, b], F[a] F[b, c], F[a] F[b] F[c]} *)

applyDistributed[F, a + b + c]

(* {F[a, b, c], F[c] + F[a, b], F[a] + F[b, c], F[a] + F[b] + F[c]} *)

applyDistributed[F, a . b . c . d]

(* {F[a, b, c, d], F[a, b, c] . F[d], F[a] . F[b, c, d], F[a, b] . F[c, d], 
 F[a, b] . F[c] . F[d], F[a] . F[b, c] . F[d], F[a] . F[b] . F[c, d], 
 F[a] . F[b] . F[c] . F[d]} *)
```

Comment: very nicely done!

Comment: Oh that's great that it works with any head. Amazing!

Answer (score 5):

One way to achieve that is to start from

```
list = {a, b, c};
```

and after you generate all the sublists

```
res = Internal`PartitionRagged[list, #] & /@ 
  Apply[Join, Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[list]]]
```

> [image: list]

you can apply a function on the above result

```
ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{foo}] @@@ res
```

> [image: res]

As you see I have used a new resource function, available to us as of 2022 which is called [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/). This is a development thanks to @Sjoerd Smit.

It was first suggested [**`here`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157305/function-addition-declaring-function-as-the-total-of-a-list-of-functions/277661#277661). In the comment section under the answer @Sjoerd Smit gives motivation for its development and subsequent use for those interested. It was further used [**`in this thread`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256096/perform-apply-to-a-sum-of-objects/278692#278692) if you want to further study it.

Comment: ThroughOperator noted, thanks! Also thank you for the references

Comment: @Albercoc glad I was able to help. Check the other answer by BobHanlon. It's more direct and really elegant :)

Comment: (+1) Very nice. Without being pedantic, I think (since v11.1) that `TakeList` could be substituted for ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` (but you probably already know that)?  : `res2=TakeList[list,#]&/@Apply[Join, Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[list]]]`

Comment: @user1066 you are not being pedantic at all. Indeed, `TakeList` should have been the go-to approach, I just like undocumented stuff. Maybe a bit too much (blushing)

Answer (score 5):

```
alist = {a, b, c};
ReplaceList[alist, {w__, x___, y___} ->
     {F @@ {w}, F @@ {x}, F @@ {y}}
    ] /. F[] :> Nothing // DeleteDuplicates // Dot @@@ # &
```

> {F[a] . F[b, c], F[a] . F[b] . F[c], F[a, b] . F[c], F[a, b, c]}